# It is possible to loop by Id and inside execute the operation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I show by example:

```
insie:
ID    date_start      date_end
1     2017-01-01     2017-12-01
1     2017-12-02     2018-06-02
1     2018-06-03     2018-06-04
2     2017-01-01     2017-12-01
2     2017-12-04     2018-06-04
3     2017-01-01     2017-12-01
3     2017-12-06     2018-06-08
```

I want to choose next to last date_end and last date_start in each ID:

```
outside:
ID    date_start      date_end
1     2018-06-03     2018-06-02
2     2017-12-04     2017-12-01
3     2017-12-06     2017-12-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to approach this. How about:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(...)
unique_ids = np.unique(df["ID"].values)

filtered_data = []
for id in unique_ids:
  temp_df = df.copy()
  temp_df = temp_df[temp_df["ID"] == id]
  temp_df = temp_df.tail(2)

  # Now build out some 2D array
  filtered_data.append([id, temp_df.iat[0,2], temp_df.iat[1,1]])

# Cast the filtered_data to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data=filtered_data, columns=["ID", "date_start", "date_end")
```

Like I said, there's lot of way to do this. It depends on what works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could simply iterate over the dataframe like this:

```py
for id, row in df.iterrows():
    start_date = df.iloc[id]["date_start"]
    end_date = df.iloc[id]["date_end"]
    ## Your code here
```

Please let me know if this solves your question. :D